# how to understand a table of tables in lua?

Tags: lua

```
    > polyline = {color = "blue", thickness = 2, npoints = 4, {x=0,y=0}, {x=-10,y=0}, {x=-10,y=1}, {x=0,y=1}}
    > print(polyline[2])
    table: 0x55ad5c0f3f90
    > print(polyline[2].x)
-10
```

Why does print(polyline[2]) give out -10 ?

Comment: the usualy way to learn a programming language is to read the manual and do some tutorials. you do not post stackoverflow questions for every line of code so someone explains it to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not provide a key explicitly, table elements are assigned to numeric keys within the table constructor.

```
polyline = {color = "blue", thickness = 2, npoints = 4, {x=0,y=0}, {x=-10,y=0}, {x=-10,y=1}, {x=0,y=1}}
```

is equivalent to

```
do
  polyline = {}
  polyline.color = "blue"
  polyline.thickness = 2
  polyline.npoints = 4
  do
    polyline[1] = {}
    polyline[1].x = 0
    polyline[1].y = 0
  end
  do
    polyline[2] = {}
    polyline[2].x = -10
    polyline[2].y = 0
  end
  do
    polyline[3] = {}
    polyline[3].x = -10
    polyline[3].y = 1
  end
  do
    polyline[4] = {}
    polyline[4].x = 0
    polyline[4].y = 1
  end
end
```

Refer to

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9

Comment: Do you have a tool that converts the code in the first block to the code in the second block?

Comment: @lhf nope. I had nothing better to do while chewing my lunch. =D